# Creating an Android ticker app RSS feed

Tags: android, rss, news-ticker

I'm trying to find some information on how to create an android app for my website's RSS feed. My website is updated on a regular biases and I would like to create something for my users to view new content added in real-time. I have some PHP, jquery knowledge but, it could be better :)

Do you know of any resources on-line on how to create something like this please.

Answer (score 0):

Go through these links , to know about development in Android

```
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html
```

About networking

```
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html
```

Parsing XMl

```
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
```

LIst UI component

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html
```

To hold list view data

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
```